# How to user power function from sql in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to round numbers, but i dont know how to write this in javascript, in sql is like this:

```
charge/POWER(10,3)
```

So it will round it on 3 decimals in way when i have nubmer 2 i will get 0,002, for number 2000 i will get 2 and so on. Is there power function in javascript, such as in sql. Any suggestion?

I tried to use pad number but that is not that, it will add only some number before , and not decimal places. Also `toFixed` it will round number to some decimal.

Comment: `num/Math.pow(10, 3);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So it will round it on 3 decimals...

Not true, it will only divide a number by 1000 (10 to the power of 3) without any rounding nor anything else - for example, try your formula with 0.2 and you'll get a number with 4 decimals.

So the Javascript equivalent is division by 1000, there are many ways to do it:

```
x / 1000
x / Math.pow(10, 3)
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var charge = 5000;
console.log(charge / 10e3) // 5
console.log(charge / 10e2) // 50
console.log(charge / 10e5) // 0.05
```

Probably this is what you want

Or you can use

```
Math.pow(10, 3)
Math.pow(10, 5)
...
```